# Getting average length of words in sentence Java

Tags: java

The code I have seems to be nearly right. The answer I get is 3.0 but it should be 2.6.I have Googled/looked at other stackoverflow answers but I don't have a fix. Been trying to do this error for 2 hours.

Code:

```
public class Sentence { // words holds the array.
private static String[] words = {"hi","my","name","is","Bob"};
}

public String toString() { //Returns the array into Strings.
    return Arrays.toString(words);
}

    public double meanLength(String s) { 
    String wordysplit[] = toString().split(", ");
    float numWords = wordysplit.length;
    float totalChar = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
        totalChar += wordysplit[i].length();

    }
    return (totalChar / numWords);
}    

public static void main(String[] args) // Really simplified this code to make it
cleaner for you guys
System.out.println("Mean word length:"+words.meanLength());

       }
}
```

Appreciate all help. Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would happen if you do `float numWords = wordysplit.length * 1.0;`, ` totalChar += wordysplit[i].length() * 1.0;` and `return ((totalChar / numWords) * 1.0;`

Comment: Please be aware that you have a curly brace ending your Sentence class; I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: @alephtwo Yeah, sorry that was a mistake

Comment: @npinti Had to change from float to double for it to work but it still gives 3.0.

Comment: I see. I thought that it might be doing some integer conversions in the background.

Comment: The problem here is that there are two extra square brackets added when using `Arrays.toString`. I don't really know why this is a duplicate. It is the same problem, with a different error.

Comment: @bob9123 https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/8bcb031bd210117d9cd5

Comment: @dovy Worked perfectly. Thanks very much. Quick question, what is the difference between adding parameters/arguments in meanLength()? When I take it out it makes no difference to the actual result

Comment: @bob9123 I have a little mistake, let see new version of gist file

Answer (score 1):

Here an easier way of doing this

```
String resultString = StringUtils.join(words, "");
float avg = (float)resultString.length() / words.length;
```

Note that `StringUtils` is a class from `Apache` commons.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

If you don't want to add `Apache commons` to your project, then you can use this simple algorithm to create a `String` from your array :

```
String[] array = {"AB", "B", "C"};
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(String s : array) {
    builder.append(s);
}

System.out.println((float)builder.toString().length() / array.length);
```

Would print `1.3333334` as `avg`.

Comment: It says join (Java.util.Collection,String) In StringUtils cannot be applied to Java.lang.String[]) . After I imported import com.sun.deploy.util.StringUtils;

Comment: Ok trying other method.

Comment: I won't be able to use that code as there is not a fixed amount of elements in my array. They always change. So I don't know if using "/3" if I have 6+ elements will work